# Sending GET Requests from Online Server to Local Server?

Tags: php, get, ubuntu-14.04

So this is the situation: I have a bunch of Arduinos and Raspberry Pis along with an ubuntu server on a local network. The arduinos and pis communicate with that local server routinely using PHP GET & POST requests.

Now this local server sometimes "fetches" something from a remote server in the cloud (also using PHP GETs) to respond to local requests from Arduinos and Pis.

**Now here's the problem:** The local server has no issues communicating with the remote server by GETs, but what if I want the server in the cloud to send a GET to the local server?

This part is kind of confusing to me as the local server is on a regular LAN and connects to the internet via a router through a local commercial ISP that issues dynamic IPs.

**How can I send PHP GETs from an "online" server to a local server?**

Please note that both servers are running Apache/PHP/MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: You can use [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net) to get the external IP of your home network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two steps to accomplish that.

*step 1 - make router forward external requests to LAN server*

*step 2 - make external server know the current dynamic WAN ip*

### step 1:

The router has to be configured to forward WAN requests to your LAN server. Assuming you use a normal home router, you typically point your browser towards the router ip and login on the router. Now you have to find where to configure forwarding (unfortunately naming of this feature varies from router to router).

While you typically can define an "exposed host" where just all external requests go to, you are better of in terms of security if you just forward specific ports to your server. As you are going to use HTTP protocol, the standard ports here would be 80 (http) and 443 (https). So assuming you use HTTPS with default port, a typical forwarding would be:

router WAN ip, port 443 --> server LAN ip, port 443

This forwards any external request to the router on port 443 to your internal server on port 443.

Now your server should be able to receive those requests, but you still would need to know your router's current dynamic WAN ip.

### step 2:

As your router's WAN ip changes from time to time, you need to somehow announce that ip to your external server.

One easy way of doing is by using an external service which will provide you with a URL, which will resolve to your current ip. This is often referred to as DDNS or dynamic DNS. One quite well known DDNS provider is https://dyn.com/dns/ - but there are plenty others, and you will even find free ones. After registering with such a provider you will be given a URL which your external server can use instead of the ip.

Now you still would have to let know the DDNS provider you current dynamic WAN ip. Most easy way to do this again involves your router. Check its config for DDNS settings, typically routers do support this feature, often there are even some specific providers pre-configured. Setup your router with the credentials you got from the DDNS provider.

Now everything is set. You should be able to send requests to your internal server by using the URL you got from your DDNS provider, while your router both forwards such requests and notifies the DDNS provider about any ip changes.

**A word of warning** - you just exposed your local server to the internet. So you will have to treat it like any server on the internet to keep it safe, including careful configuration, installing security updates and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a port on your router, and specify where the router should lead the request to. Lets assume your external ip is: 80.82.71.24, going to this ip address (fx: http://80.82.71.24) will lead to your router. Then the router decides what to do with this request, normally the request would timeoutted / refused. But on the router, if you specify that this certain request (could be: tcp/udp) (to a specified port) should point to a certain internal ip (the local server ip), then it's possible to do what you want.

But to do this, you need to read up on your router - first of all, see if you can login into it. Could you specify what router you use and if your internet connection is yours or shared (fx. campus, school, etc)?

By the way, it would not be a good idea to open up the port for the whole world, so maybe you should consider to only allow your cloud server ip to gain access to that specific port.

Comment: In his question, he says he has an `ISP that issues dynamic IPs` so I don't think this is going to work even if he gets the config right.